# Add (or Adjust) Margins in a Bclogo Box

Tags: margins, bclogo

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} \hskip 8pt 
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=red!10,  %couleur=blue!14, %couleur=blue!20, 
epBord=2.5, arrondi=0, %logo=\bcplume, %\bclampe,marge=8, 
logo= ,
%ombre=true, blur, couleurBord=blue!14, %couleurBord=blue!60,
barre=none, %barre=snake, tailleOndu=1.5
]
{\vskip -8pt {\color{black} ``The mathematician lives long and lives young; the wings of his soul do not early drop off, nor do its pores become clogged with the earthy particles blown from the dusty highways of vulgar life.'' \vskip -3pt \hfill \textit{---J. J. Sylvester}\vspace*{-10pt}}}
\end{bclogo}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

QUESTION: How may I add left and right margins so that the text does not extend all the way to the left and right hand limits of the box? i.e., to make it more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Try adding `marge=10` or similar to your code (size is to be specified in points, but without units.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my example:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
    \hskip 8pt 

\begin{bclogo}[
couleur=red!10,         % background color
marge=20,               % margin in pt
epBord=2.5,             % border width
arrondi=0,              % corner radius
ombre=true,             % shadow
blur,                   % blur
couleurBord=blue!14,    % border color
logo=,                  % no built-in logo
barre=snake,            % border style
tailleOndu=1.5          % border amplitude (zigzag)
]
{\vskip -8pt {\color{black} ``The mathematician lives long and lives young; the wings of his soul do not early drop off, nor do its pores become clogged with the earthy particles blown from the dusty highways of vulgar life.'' \vskip -3pt \hfill \textit{---J. J. Sylvester}\vspace*{-10pt}}}
\end{bclogo}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I have worked with most of your initial values, and commented them where I could. You can probably make the rest work.

[image]

(Also, I reserve judgement on the wisdom of publishing a package that not only has exclusively French documentation, but also uses French parameters. But that's clearly not your fault …)

Comment: Thank you kindly for this very helpful answer.